# Bing maps to get hospitals

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, bing-maps

I am trying to fetch all the hospitals for specific cities in India using BING Map APIs for Windows 8 Metro application. However i am not able to fetch the details. Following are the two approaches that are tried

1. Using NearbyVenueCollection class

   ```
       NearbyVenueOptions options = new NearbyVenueOptions(loc, 10000);

       NearbyVenueCollection nearbyVenues = null;
       try
       {
           nearbyVenues = await MyMap.VenueManager.GetNearbyVenuesAsync(options); ;
       }
       catch (Exception)
       {
       }
       if (nearbyVenues != null && nearbyVenues.Count > 0)
       {
           foreach (var nearbyVenue in nearbyVenues)
           {
               if (nearbyVenue.Metadata.VenueType == VenueType.Hospital.ToString())
               {
                   string name = nearbyVenue.Metadata.Name;
               }
           }
       }
   ```

This is not providing the required details.

1. Using Bing Spatial Data Services

Following is the code snippet

```
////Create the Bing Spatial Data Services request to get nearby POI
string findNearbyPOIRequest = "http://spatial.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/data/            f22876ec257b474b82fe2ffcb8393150/ NavteqNA/NavteqPOIs? spatialfilter=nearby("
+ loc.Latitude + "," + loc.Longitude + "," + 1000 + ")"
+ "&$filter=EntityTypeID%20EQ%20'" + "8060" + "'&               $select=EntityID,DisplayName,__Distance,Latitude,Longitude,AddressLine,         Locality,AdminDistrict,PostalCode,Phone&$top=20"
+ "&key=" + BingCredentials;


Uri uri = new Uri(findNearbyPOIRequest);
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);

// GetResponseAsync() returns immediately after the header is ready 
WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
Stream inputStream = response.GetResponseStream();

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(inputStream);
XNamespace m ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata";
XNamespace d = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";
MapLayer pushpinLayer = new MapLayer();
pushpinLayer.Name = "Push Pin Layer";

var elements = from nodes in doc.Descendants(m + "properties")
               select new
               {
                   Name = nodes.Element(d + "DisplayName").Value,
                   Latitude = nodes.Element(d + "Latitude").Value,
                   Longitude = nodes.Element(d + "Longitude").Value,
                   Address = nodes.Element(d + "AddressLine").Value,
               };
```

However i am not getting the required details for cities in India. Can someone help me figure out what need to be done in order to fetch correct details?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259692.aspx

Comment: The link which is provided is AJAX control. Can this be used within Windows 8 metro applications?

Answer (score 0):

The Venue maps are only locations where Bing Maps has indoor floor plans. I'm not aware of any hospitals in India that are available as Venue Maps. The point of interest data in the Bing Spatial Data services is only available in North America and Europe. Your best option for finding locations in India is to use the Bing Maps SOAP Search Service.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980849.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd221354.aspx

Comment: Can BING map SOAP services be used inside Windows 8 Store App?

Comment: Yes. Add it as a service reference.

Comment: Thanks @rbrundritt. I would definitely try and let you know.

Comment: It doesnt work. I am not sure if it is because of my India location. I tried out the locations specified in the link and it worked for those locations.